# Hiding Filter Pane server side in Power BI asp.net

Tags: asp.net, powerbi-embedded

I am using the embedded Power BI in .NET, rendering the report using Power BI Rest APIs GetReportInGroup.
There is a need to hide the Power BI filter.

I could hide it using JavaScript in our view by setting `filterPaneEnabled = false` in config.
We also did hide some filters inside pbix.

Is there any way to hide it when calling Power BI REST APIs not using Javascript so it will be server-side?

Answer (score 1):

No, many users are waiting for this feature to be added, there is no other way than the ones you mentioned.